# Как сделать, чтобы DrawerLayout был поверх ActionBar?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы выдвижная панель выезжала на всю высоту экрана (высоту, а не ширину, с шириной все ясно). Я имею ввиду, чтобы она заезжала на меню и как сделать так, чтобы она не заезжала на меню.
То есть, вопрос сводится к тому, от чего это зависит?

Comment: уточните вопрос, т.к. фраза "Я имею ввиду, чтобы она заезжала на меню и как сделать так, чтобы она не заезжала на меню." противоречива, и о каком меню идет речь?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того как верстать. По макету, который предоставляет Android Studio при создание проекта, у вас автоматически сверстано как по гайдлайнам, т.е. с заездом на `Toolbar`. Для того чтобы она не заезжала на Toolbar, можно либо по другому сверстать, либо поставить `margin`